# Java class files are not generated in war file

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, dropwizard, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to deploy project in tomcat.
After deploying my war file,it doesn't work.While clicking link shows 404 error.

webapps--> project-->WEB-INF-->classes-->only files from src/main/resources were generated.

Class files from src/main/java were not generated in war file.I think,it is not compiling the subpackages in src/main/java.I have all java class files in subpackages. 
Please help me,if anyone knows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <groupId>com.nestone.deals</groupId>
    <artifactId>dealcatcher</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Deal Catcher</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <dropwizard.version>0.9.0-rc4</dropwizard.version>
        <mainClass>com.nestone.deals.DealCatcherApplication</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-forms</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-assets</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-views</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-views-mustache</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.49.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.49.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.49.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.bitwalker</groupId>
            <artifactId>UserAgentUtils</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.knowm</groupId>
            <artifactId>sundial</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <!-- exclude signed Manifests -->
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportPlugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.4</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                                <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.8.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </reportPlugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[image]

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382461/maven-not-compiling-class-and-there-is-no-class-files-in-war-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475054/compiled-classes-missing-in-war-file

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml? Might be an incorrect src directory configuration.

Comment: How are you building your project? Do you use eclipse to generate the war or are you using a Maven command? Have you tried building the project with `mvn clean compile war:war`?

Comment: Building project using maven.Used mvn clean compile war:war showing as build success,but no java class files generated

Comment: I have tried you pom.xml in my workspace and added a simple class. Using `mvn clean compile war:war` I am getting a war file that contains the compiled classes under `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: In case this is an issue in the IDE, I would recommend to check the deployment assembly settings in the project preferences and check whether the m2e-wtp extension is installed (comes as a default in the STS distribution).